# making input field editable after using innerText and calling an API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an input field in ionic that triggers an API call when the character length typed by the user is >3, `company(event, coParam)`
The JSON response displays on a list

```
<ion-list id="coDisplayItem">
<ion-item *ngFor = "let coItem of companyData" (click)="coItemTapped( coItem)">
  <h2>{{coItem.name}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

I am then using a method `coItemTapped(coItem)` to set the text in the ion-input field to the item that the user has tapped using `document.getElementById('coInputField').innerText = coItem.name;`
**I want to make the ion-input field editable again and trigger the api call if the user taps on the ion-input field again**, how can i achive this ? 
Below is the complete code

```
<ion-item class="custBackground" >
<ion-label floating style="color: white;">Company</ion-label>
<ion-input (input)="company($event, coParam)" id="coInputField"></ion-input>
```

```
company(event, coParam){
this.storage.get('token').then(authData=>{
  this.token = authData.access_token;
  if(event.target.value.length > 3){
    var userCoInput = event.target.value;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Authorization','Bearer '+this.token);
    headers.set('Content-Type','application/json');
    var coUrl = 'https://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx'+userCoInput;

    var coResponse = this.http.get(coUrl, {headers: headers}).map(res=>res.json())
    .subscribe((coData=>{
      this.companyData = coData.result.Company;
      //alert(this.companyData);
    }), Error=>{
      let subscribeAlert = this.atrCtrl.create({
        title: 'Search Exhausted',
        subTitle: 'We could not find any results for your search!',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      subscribeAlert.present();
    });
  }
}, Error=>{
  let authAlert = this.atrCtrl.create({
    title: 'Authentication Check',
    subTitle: 'Something went wrong with your login session!',
    buttons: ['OK']
  });
  authAlert.present();
})
}

//for item tapped by user
   coItemTapped(coItem){
this.id = coItem.id;
document.getElementById('coInputField').innerText = coItem.name;
}
```

Any suggestions will be great help

Comment: Why not use `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: thanks a ton! this works, I have also managed to call the API again.